# Cannot find package '/apollo-server-express/' imported from `server/index.js`

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to run my express server on my digital ocean droplet. I've ran `npm install` but when I run `npm run startServer` I get the error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/root/ti4-automation/node_modules/apollo-server-express/' imported from /root/ti4-automation/server/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:316:9)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:896:14)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:958:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1173:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:173:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:852:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:439:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

My `startServer` script does `"startServer": "nodemon ./server/index.js",`

My `index.js` has

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express'
```

In my `package.json` I do have

`"apollo-server-express": "^3.11.1",`
`"type": "module",`

And when I navigate to the folder `/root/ti4-automation/node_modules/apollo-server-express/` I can see it's there.

I've also ran the following:

`rm -r node_modules` > `npm install`

But the error persists. Locally everything works as expected.

Comment: did you try specifying extension (.js) sometimes this works.

Comment: On what? `apollo-server-express.js`? that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to go a tier higher with my droplet (from 6$ p/m to 7$ p/m) and now I'm not having any issues. On the previous droplet I did have an issue with NPM install crashing the first time.